# format number with locale to fixed decimal places

Tags: java, kotlin

What's the correct way to format a number with a given locale AND with given decimal places.

If I'd have the following code:

```
fun main() {
    val number = BigDecimal("1000");
    println(formatNumber(number,Locale("de","DE"),2)) // should print 1.000,00
    println(formatNumber(number,Locale("de","CH"),3)) // should print 1'000.000
}
```

How should formatNumber be implemented?

I've found 2 common ways to format numbers in kotlin on the internet, but both don't fully satisfy the needs:

## DecimalFormat

```
fun formatNumber(number: BigDecimal, locale: Locale, decimalPlaces: Int) = DecimalFormat("#,###."+("0".repeat(decimalPlaces))).format(number)
```

Drawback: Lacks localization

## NumberFormat

```
fun formatNumber(number: BigDecimal, locale: Locale, decimalPlaces: Int) = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).format(number)
```

Drawback: Lacks Decimal places

Is there a way that ticks all boxes? I feel like NumberFormat should be the way to go, but I can't figure out how to specify the decimal places..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` on the number format:

```
fun formatNumber(number: BigDecimal, locale: Locale, decimalPlaces: Int) =
    with(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale)) {
        maximumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces
        minimumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces
        format(number)
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! Didn't realize these were setters as well..

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `DecimalFormat` which indeed supports localization through the `DecimalFormatSymbols` parameter:

```
DecimalFormat("#,###."+("0".repeat(decimalPlaces)), DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale))
    .format(number)
```

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks. Although I'll still go the NumberFormat way as it handles the case with zero decimal places correctly. Wouldn't be hard to fix, but it feels cleaner with NumberFormat.

Comment: @VanCoding sure, choose what best suits you :)